# Windows Phone 8.1 Suspend

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 app - I'm completely new to Win Phone development!

It contains various Pages and custom UserControls.

I am trying to suspend the app to access the filesystem/camera.

Initially I was getting an error because I was passing complex objects in `Frame.Navigate` but I resolved that by adding the complex object to `SuspensionManager.SessionState["..."]` and retrieving it in the `OnNavigatedTo` function.

Now, the error I am getting as the app suspends, is:

> Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

I tried to do what it suggested - Added the `[DataContract]` attribute to the class and `[DataMember]` to all properties and fields.

I still got the same error. Google doesn't offer a lot of help except to try the above, so I wen through every custom UserControl and added the attributes to those - still didn't work, so I added the attributes to every Page also - mainly out of desperation.

So now everything should be serializable but I still get the same error! I doubt it's useful but here's the stacktrace:

> at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.CheckAndAdd(Type type, Dictionary`2 typesChecked, Dictionary`2& nameToDataContractTable)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContractsForKnownTypes(IList`1 knownTypeList)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.get_KnownDataContracts()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.get_SerializerKnownDataContracts()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContractFromSerializerKnownTypes(XmlQualifiedName qname)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.ResolveDataContractFromKnownTypes(String typeName, String typeNs, DataContract memberTypeContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.IsKnownType(DataContract dataContract, Type declaredType)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
>      at WriteKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
>      at WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
>      at eAuditWindowsPhone.Common.SuspensionManager.d__0.MoveNext()

I'm really not sure what to try next? I'd welcome some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to serialize some Element from your UI. That's hardly possible and you just should not do that. You would need to make everything that appears in the UserControl, every property and their types, serializable.

You can only add Attributes (DataContract or DataMember) to classes you created yourself and you will not be able make UI Elements serializeable.
Might be, your UserControl is a DataContract, but it still has some properties of type UIElement, which will not be serializable.

---

**Answer:**
You should just store the **Values** you are interested in (Like TextBox.Text or ToggleButton.IsActive, ...).

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't serializing anything at first. The error just happened by default. It was only then that I started adding the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes. Do you think the `Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement' cannot be serialized` be a red herring and the serialization issue be elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, the navigation parameters and session state get serialized by the suspension manager. And you are putting something in there, that contains a reference to a UI Element (and that property seems to have a data member attribute).

Comment: So basically: SessionState isn't the right place for complex objects too. :) You should just drop em and recreate them, if the app actually has to be restarted.

Comment: hmm OK - that makes sense. So my scenario is   - A list of Questions, user taps a question and it opens a Question Page. I was passing the Question directly in `Frame.Navigate` - which I've found is not correct, so then I stored it in `SuspensionManager` which apparently is also not correct. I suppose I could pass the QuestionID and reload from the database on the Question Page. I guess this would work, but would you have a better idea?

Comment: No, that's exactly the way you do it. Every page should be able to laugh with nothing but it's navigation parameters as input.